# Finiteness of Tate-Shafarevich

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves, reference-request

Does anyone happen to know who conjectured the finiteness of the Tate-Shafarevich group?

We recall the conjecture. Let $E/K$ be an elliptic curve where $K$ is a number field. Then $Ш(E/K)$ is finite.

Comment: For what it is worth, it does not seem to appear in the original Lang-Tate paper ("Principal Homogeneous Spaces over Abelian Varieties"), see Theorem 5 and the two preceding paragraphs on p. 681. I don't have easy access to Shafarevich's paper.

Comment: John Tate (On the conjectures of Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer and a geometric analog. Séminaire Bourbaki, 9 (1964-1966), Exposé No. 306, 26 p. http://numdam.org/numdam-bin/fitem?id=SB_1964-1966__9__415_0) says that *Another deep conjecture underlying [the Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer] Conjecture is that Ш is finite*.  He doesn't attribute this finiteness conjecture to anybody, so presumably he is the author.

Answer (score 12):

In Cassels's 1962 ICM paper (available [here](http://imu2.zib.de/ICM/ICM1962.1/)), he says the following: "Indeed, Tate and Šafarevič have, I believe, independently conjectured(5) that Ш itself is always finite", and the (5) is a footnote stating: "In his lecture, Tate denied paternity but adopted the conjecture. In conversation during the Congress Šafarevič expressed strong doubts."

So, maybe no one knows!

EDIT: As an added bonus, I found the following quote in Cassels's review of Silverman's book: "Without doubt the reviewer's most lasting contribution to the theory is the introduction of the Cyrillic letter Ш ("sha") to denote this group, a usage which has become universal."

Comment: Cassels has the same footnote ("This is the author's most lasting contribution to the subject") on p. 109 of his Lectures on Elliptic Curves.

Comment: Actually, proving the order a square when finite would seem to be a candidate. But he likes his jokes.

Comment: Perhaps he views the conceptual leap to the Cyrillic alphabet as a real game changer.

Comment: Tate told me that, when he first started thinking about elliptic curves, he assumed that Ш would be finite and that it would be easy to prove it, in analogy with the class group. He then realized that matters were much more difficult.